# Confusion on elementary set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi I have confusion on this.
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[0+\frac 1 {n+1} ; 1 - \frac 1 {n+1}\right]=(0;1)$$
Why when $n$ goes to infinity, $0+1/(n+1)$ cannot be $0$.
$$\left[0+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 {n+1} ; 1 - \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 {n+1}\right]=[0,1]$$
But in this case when $n$ goes to infinity can be $0$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What in particular is confusing?

Comment: Hint: Think about exactly what $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty$ means.

Comment: I am not quite sure the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I the first formula none of the sets making up the union actually contain 0 or 1,
For an element to be a member of a union it must be an element of at least on of the sets being combined and since $1/(n+1)$ is never actually zero, none of the individual intervals contain the boundary points. However, the limit of $1/(n+1)$ is 0 for large $n$ since for any $x > 0$ there is an $n$ that makes $1/(n+1) < x$.
The main point of limits to be able to deal quantities like $1/n$ for large $n$ without having to try to deal with  with infinite and infinitesimal quantities explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $p$ is in $(0,1)$ and very near to zero, how large $n$ do you take to capture it in a closed interval $[\frac{1}{n+1},1-\frac{1}{n+1}]\subset(0,1)$?

**Observation:** You only need to prove $$\bigcup_n\left[\frac 1 {n+1} , 1 - \frac 1 {n+1}\right]=(0,1)$$
And this achieved if you can prove:

$$\bigcup_n\left[\frac 1 {n+1} , 1 - \frac 1 {n+1}\right]\subset(0,1),$$
and
$$\bigcup_n\left[\frac 1 {n+1} , 1 - \frac 1 {n+1}\right]\supset(0,1).$$

To get the second claim just add the two element set $\{0,1\}$ to the first.

**Warning:**

Knowing that $\infty$ is not a number **do not exist**  $n\in{\Bbb{N}}$ such that $$\frac{1}{n+1}=0.$$

Comment: see that, this is true if $0<\frac{1}{n+1}<p$, so you can say how big $n$ gotta be

Comment: but if n goes to infinity, 1/n+1 goes to 0. what is the difference between the first and the second

Comment: the first $n_0$ you found for $p$ means $p\in[\frac{1}{n_0+1},1-\frac{1}{n_0+1}]\subset\bigcup_n[\frac{1}{n+1},1-\frac{1}{n+1}]$.

Comment: In this case, but n still can be infinity. if that's the case why 1/n+1 can not be zero. why can't take the limit of 1/n+1 as n approaches to zero. sorry for too much asking......

Comment: check the edit i did

Comment: also see this: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals]